# How to use separate git branch as npm package dependency in different corresponding local branch package.json?

Tags: git, npm, bitbucket, githooks

I want to install a common-utility git repo as a dependency in my different services. For different branch on each service i want to include corresponding branch of common-utility as a dependency in package.json

**I know i can install a git module as a dependency by doing**

`npm i git+ssh://git@<gitlab_url>.git` 
or

`npm i git+ssh://git@<gitlab_url>.git#master` for a specific branch.

but using this approach i can only use a specific branch of utility in my all branches in every service.

Because when i merge the two branches, package.json also gets updated and at the end every branch have same branch of utility as dependency.

Let's say i have a Services using Utility as npm module and service has 2 branches `master` and `staging`

**Current Scenario**

`utility#master -> ServiceA#master`

`utility#master -> ServiceA#staging`

**What i actually want**

`utility#master -> ServiceA#master`

`utility#staging -> ServiceA#staging`

Is there any workaround by which i can keep corresponding branch as dependency and even after merging two branches it follow similar pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there would be a proper way to attain what you said, since it sounds a bit weird that you would have 2 different text in same place on 2 different branches.

But I think I could suggest 2 solutions to your problem, yet I want to clearly give you a heads up that I don't think that either of them is a good approach.
    1. One would be to have both the branches separately and not merge them both, but instead merge the changes branch or develop branches onto both of them after making the changes.
    2. I guess you might need to have a separate small project within your repo that checks the the env file for environment type and rewrites the package.json of your project with whichever version of dependency you need and runs the install script.

A similar discussion happened on [github](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10661), but unfortunately no solution.

Comment: I have currently written a script that gets executed whenever i pull push code from git and modify package.json, script is run via git-hooks. I was wondering if there is better approach.

Comment: I read on the github issue that there's no built-in support for npm like that but its there for maven etc. So I guess either your approach or mine should work like a hack.